# Do word vectors mean anything on their own?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, word2vec, text-analysis, word-embedding

From my understanding, word vectors are only ever used in terms of relations to other word vectors. For example, the word vector for "king" minus the word vector for "boy" should give a vector close to "queen".

Given a vector of some unknown word, can assumptions about the word be made based solely on the values of that vector?

Comment: no, there is no meaning in word2vec values.

Comment: @lejlot, of course there's meaning. What you're trying to do is encoding the meaning of the word, so if you understand what the dimensions are, then you can glean that the word `him` is more masculine than feminine. But if your algorithm doesn't encode masculinity, then there might not be a difference between `him` and `her`.

Comment: @ACVM the comment is related to word2vec, as described by Mikolov. There is no (interpretable!) meaning in these embeddings values, as the loss is defined purely on the dot products of pairs of words. Consequently it is rotation invariant, for any embedding E if you rotate it by any angle - loss is the same, thus there cannot be any axis-aligned meaning "in general" unless you explicitly add it to the objective. So unless one analyses entire embedding - there cannot be any reasoning based on these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The individual coordinates – such as dimension #7 of a 300-dimensional vector, etc – don't have easily interpretable meanings.

It's primarily the relative *distances* to other words (neighborhoods), and relative *directions* with respect to other constellations of words (orientations without regard to the perpendicular coordinate axes, that may be vaguely interpretable, because they correlate with natural-language or natural-thinking semantics.

Further, the pre-training initialization of the model, and much of the training itself, uses randomization. So even on the exact same data, words can wind up in different coordinates on repeated training runs.

The resulting word-vectors should after each run be about as useful *with respect to each other*, in terms of distances and directions, but neighborhoods like "words describing seasons" or "things that are 'hot'" could be in very different places in subsequent runs. Only vectors that trained together are comparable.

(There are some constrained variants of word2vec that try to force certain dimensions or directions to be more useful for certain purposes, such as answering questions or detecting hypernym/hyponym relationships – but that requires extra constraints or inputs to the training process. Plain vanilla word2vec won't be as cleanly interpretable.)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make assumptions about the word based on the values of its word vector. A single word vector does not carry information or meaning by itself, but only contains meaning in relation to other word vectors.

Word vectors using algorithms such as Word2Vec and GloVe are computed and rely on the co-occurrence of words in a sequence. As an example, Word2Vec employs the dot product of two vectors as an input to a softmax function, which approximates the conditional probability that those two words appear in the same sequence. Word vectors are then determined such that words that frequently occur in the same context are mapped to similar vectors. Word vectors thereby capture both syntactic and semantic information.